# How can i write HQL for SYSDATE?

Tags: hibernate, hql

I have condition which is checking the current date - 3.

```
select * from TABLE_1 SYSDATE-3 >= TABLE_1.created_date
```

How should i write in Hibernate query language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write HQL using your entities.

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-examples

There are some examples which are using sysdate.

Comment: Is this advisable to use SYSDATE-3 in hql?

Comment: if sysdate-3 registerd in your HQL dialect then you can use it.

Comment: SYSDATE is not registered. I am trying to use oracle SYSDATE.

Answer (score 5):

For Oracle SQL dialect use `sysdate()` like in this example:

```
select e
from Entity e
where (e.endDate is null or (e.endDate > sysdate()))
```

This is valid for `orm.xml` or when using a `<named-query>`

For your particular query "all rows that have not been created in the last three days" use this:

```
select e from Entity e where to_date(sysdate() - 3) >= e.created_date
```